# Парсинг таблицы на сайте Bs4. Соединяются ячейки, почему так

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Пытаюсь вытащить текст всех ячеек из таблицы на сайте https://schedule.irkat.ru/?group=%D0%91%D0%94-20-1.

При проходе циклом по списку элементов `raspisanie` иногда выдает текст, расположенный в двух разных ячкйках. Из-за чего это происходит и как исправить? Нужно вносить текст одной ячейки, в один элемент списка `clear_raspisanie`.

Мой код парсера:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b


URL = 'https://schedule.irkat.ru/?group=%D0%91%D0%94-20-1'

r = requests.get(URL)
soup = b(r.text, 'html.parser')
raspisanie = soup.find_all('td')
clear_raspisanie = [c.text for c in raspisanie]


print(raspisanie)
print(clear_raspisanie)
```

Вывод кода списка `clear_raspisanie`:

`['08:30-10:00', 'МДК 01.01 Разработка программных модулей (каб. 209  208)', 'нет нет  ', 'нет  ', '', '', '10:10-11:40', 'МДК 01.01 Разработка программных модулей (каб. 209  208)', 'нет БЖД (каб. 223)  ', 'БЖД (каб. 223)', '', '', '12:10-13:40', 'МДК 01.01 Разработка программных модулей (каб. 209  208)', 'Классный час (каб. 221)', 'МДК 01.02 Поддержка и тестирование программных модулей (каб. 228)', '', '', '13:50-15:20', '', 'МДК 01.01 Разработка программных модулей (каб. 228)', 'МДК 01.02 Поддержка и тестирование программных модулей (каб. 228)', '', '', '15:50-17:20', '', 'МДК 01.01 Разработка программных модулей (каб. 209  230)', '', '', '', '17:30-19:00', '', 'МДК 01.04 Системное программирование (каб. 209)', '', '', '']` # отформатирован, только текст

Как можно увидеть есть такие элементы в списке как `'нет нет   '` или `' нет БЖД'`, хотя на сайте они в разных ячейках

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вы допишите в код:

```
for c in raspisanie:
    print(c)
```

И увидите, что там, где выводится текст сразу нескольких ячеек, открывается сразу несколько тегов `<td>` друг в друге. Это ответ на вопрос, почему так выходит.

Ответ на вопрос как исправить:

Можете, например, использовать более строгий парсер html5lib. Он умеет работать с битым html-кодом.

В коде `soup = b(r.text, 'html.parser')` меняете на `soup = b(r.text, 'html5lib')`

Может понадобиться установить модуль `html5lib`. Для этого в консоли системы выполните: `pip install html5lib`

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас буду пробывать, огромное спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста. Если это решает вашу проблему, нажмите на кнопку принять ответ.

Comment: Еще раз огромное спасибо, я потратил целый день на фикс этой ошибки, а все это решаемо за 5 минут. Вы мне очень сильно помогли:)